# WPF where to store NLog logs

Tags: wpf, logging, nlog

Is "Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData" suitable for storing an NLog log file in a Clickonce WPF application running under .net client profile?

Needs to support XP upwards.

Thanks

[Update]
In case it helps, I've blogged about using NLog with WPF [here](http://bit.ly/gsNrHQ)

Comment: From my point of view it's quite indicated to put all of your files in there because otherwise you could end up with security problems on Vista or Win7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think it would be, as long as you are consistent in your code.

I would probably put it in a subfolder named after my application, just to keep it tidy.